# Flot Charts. Custom color below x-axis value

Tags: javascript, flot

I have a Flot Bar Chart code.

```
$(function() {  
        var barOptions = {
            series: {
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.4,
                    fill: true,
                    fillColor: {
                        colors: [{
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }, {
                            opacity: 0.8
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                mode: "categories",
                tickLength: 0 
            },              
            yaxis: {
                min:-200, max: 200,  tickSize: 50,
            },
            colors: ["#1ab394"],
            grid: {
                color: "#999999",
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
                borderWidth:0
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            },
            tooltip: true,
            tooltipOpts: {
                content: "Cost: %y %"
            }
        };

        var barData = {
            label: "bar",
            data: [         
            ["First", -100],["Second", 66.67],["Third", -177.77],]

        };

        $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"), [barData], barOptions);            

    });
```

I want that every bar below 0 would be specific (for example red) color. I have tried to do that with threshold plugin, but it adds additional values. Is there any solution to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threshold plugin should not add additional values, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9v7e2694/) or the snippet below:

```js
$(function() {
    var barOptions = {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.4,
                fill: true,
                fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 0.8
                    }, {
                        opacity: 0.8
                    }]
                },
                align: 'center'
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            tickLength: 0,
            ticks: [
                [1, 'First'],
                [2, 'Second'],
                [3, 'Third']
            ]
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: -200,
            max: 200,
            tickSize: 50,
        },
        colors: ["#1ab394"],
        grid: {
            color: "#999999",
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: true,
            tickColor: "#D4D4D4",
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            content: "Cost: %y %"
        }
    };

    var barData = {
        label: "bar",
        data: [
            [1, -100],
            [2, 66.67],
            [3, -177.77],
        ],
        threshold: {
            below: 0,
            color: "rgb(200, 20, 30)"
        },
    };

    $.plot($("#flot-bar-chart"), [barData], barOptions);

});
```

```css
#flot-bar-chart {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.threshold.min.js"></script>
<div id="flot-bar-chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You. It was because my x-axis had no ticks. Maybe you know is it possible to display numbers on top of the x-axis? Because now I can't see some numbers and I can't do a smaller stepSize either. http://i.imgur.com/bpMak0J.png

Comment: Your y axis minimum is only -100 instead of -200. And for the really small bar you would need a color for the bar labels which is readable on the background e.g. black.